# variable not in scope - tail recursive sum - Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, scope, tail-recursion

I am stuck with the `variable not in scope: m` error. 
This is supposed to be a code to sum n numbers in a tail recursion way.

```
zum :: Integer-> Integer 
zum n = add_sum m n where
add_sum :: Integer-> Integer-> Integer
add_sum m n
    | n == 0    = m
    | otherwise = add_sum (m+n) (n-1)
```

Comment: In your line `zum n = add_sum m n` where do you define `m`?

Comment: ahh, yes! thanks! It is that line. I  found the problem!  It should be: zum n = add_sum 0 n where

Comment: good. you can add an answer (it is allowed) and accept it, to mark the issue resolved.

Comment: done! thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is tail-recursive, by the way. The compiler might be smart enough to recognize it, but using guards is syntactic sugar for a large if/else expression. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your function will expand to `if n == 0 then m else if (n - 1) == 0 then m+1 else if ...`. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092864/tail-recursion-in-haskell). You want to define `add_sum` in a way that it matches against the arguments rather than using guards.

Comment: @Mokosha hmm, I hesitate now too. I will read a bit more about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of your code

```
zum n = add_sum m n where
```

'm' is not defined. Perhaps it was intended that instead of an 'm', there needs to be 0 there.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps cleaner this way?

```
sum n = go 0 n
     where go m 0 = m
           go m n = go (m+n) (n-1)


> sum 4
10
```